# MLP for regression using PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch, mlp

I am trying to implement a MLP with 3 hidden layers for a regression task. My code runs but the loss is always "nan" so something is wrong and have not been able to figure it out.  Here is my implementaiton:

```
#Import 
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, TensorDataset
import torch.optim as optim

#Prepare data
X_train_tensor = torch.tensor(train_data_top.drop(columns=['DATE','permno','RET']).values, dtype=torch.float32)
y_train_tensor = torch.tensor(train_data_top['RET'].values, dtype=torch.float32)

X_test_tensor = torch.tensor(test_data_top.drop(columns=['DATE','permno','RET']).values, dtype=torch.float32)
y_test_tensor = torch.tensor(test_data_top['RET'].values, dtype=torch.float32)

X_val_tensor = torch.tensor(val_data_top.drop(columns=['DATE','permno','RET']).values, dtype=torch.float32)
y_val_tensor = torch.tensor(val_data_top['RET'].values, dtype=torch.float32)

train_dataset = TensorDataset(X_train_tensor, y_train_tensor)
test_dataset = TensorDataset(X_test_tensor, y_test_tensor)
val_dataset = TensorDataset(X_val_tensor, y_val_tensor)


batch_size = 256
train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
test_loader = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False)
val_loader = DataLoader(val_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False)
```

```
#MLP Model
class MLP(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size1, hidden_size2, hidden_size3, output_size):
        super(MLP, self).__init__()
        #Create fully connected layers
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(input_size, hidden_size1)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(hidden_size1, hidden_size2)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(hidden_size2, hidden_size3)
        self.fc4 = nn.Linear(hidden_size3, output_size)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc3(x))
        x = self.fc4(x)
        return x
```

```
# Adjust input_size based on the number of features in your input data
input_size = train_dataset[0][0].shape[0]
print(input_size)
hidden_size1, hidden_size2, hidden_size3 = 256, 128, 64
output_size = 1  # For regression
learning_rate = 0.0001

model = MLP(input_size, hidden_size1, hidden_size2, hidden_size3, output_size)
criterion = nn.MSELoss()  # Mean Squared Error loss for regression
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)
```

```
num_epochs = 10
#Training
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    model.train()
    for batch_x, batch_y in train_loader:
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = model(batch_x)
        loss = criterion(outputs, batch_y)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()


    #Validation
    model.eval()
    val_loss = 0.0
    with torch.no_grad():
        for val_batch_x, val_batch_y in val_loader:
            val_outputs = model(val_batch_x)
            val_loss += criterion(val_outputs, val_batch_y).item()

    val_loss /= len(val_loader)

    print(f'Epoch {epoch+1}/{num_epochs}, Loss: {loss.item():.4f}, Val Loss: {val_loss:.4f}')

print('Training finished.')
```

```
# R-squared function
def calculate_r_squared(y_true, y_pred):
    return r2_score(y_true, y_pred)

# Testing
model.eval()
test_loss = 0.0
all_predictions = []
all_targets = []

with torch.no_grad():
    for test_batch_x, test_batch_y in test_loader:
        test_outputs = model(test_batch_x)
        test_loss += criterion(test_outputs, test_batch_y).item()

        all_predictions.extend(test_outputs.numpy())
        all_targets.extend(test_batch_y.numpy())

test_loss /= len(test_loader)

# Calculate R-squared
r_squared = calculate_r_squared(all_targets, all_predictions)

print(f'Test Loss: {test_loss:.4f}')
print(f'R-squared: {r_squared:.4f}')

print('Training and Testing finished.')
```

All my data is normalized and any rosws with null values have been dropped.
The output for my epoch for loop always prints the loss at "nan"

I am not sure what is going wrong. I have already tried decreasing the learning rate. I started at 0.001 and I am currently at 0.0001

Comment: Do you have missing values in your dataset?

Comment: I'd also suggest starting your learning rate at `1e-6`

Comment: Thank you, that seems to have helped. I added a validation and testing to my implementation. Can anyone point out anything that looks incorrect? I am getting an R-squared value of -.0026, which tells me something is wrong. I am replicating a research paper and was expecting an r-squared value anywhere from 0.2 to 0.4. I have updated my code above.

Comment: You could decrease your learning rate even further to `1e-8` and increase the number of epochs. How many are used in the paper you're replicating?

Comment: I decreased LR to 1e-6. The paper does not indicate the number of epochs. R-squared value is still negative. I decreased the batch size from 256 to 64, that seems to have helped a little bit ( R-squared value for the test set is now positive). it is worth noting that I am using a different data set than the original paper. I am attempting to predict stock prices, the original paper uses the period from 1957 to 2010. I am using the period from 2010 to 2021. I was expecting the performance to be somewhat similar, maybe not? I am mostly worried about my implementation because this is my first MLP